# Poly3DCollection - set face color by scalar field defined over vertices with linear gradient

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon, matplotlib-3d

## Problem summary

I have a mesh made by quadrilateral elements with a scalar field defined over the nodes of the elements. I am using `Poly3DCollection` to plot the mesh with the elements coloured by the scalar field. However, I am forced to average the scalar field over the vertices composing each 3D polygon because I cannot find a way to have a smooth variation of the color of the faces based on the value of the scalar field at each vertex. Something similar was asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526364/fill-matplotlib-polygon-with-a-gradient-between-vertices), but the answer seems to work only for 2D paths and polygons.

## Code

Below you can find a MWE to replicate my situation. As you can see, to set the color of the faces of each 3D polygon, I have to average the scalar field defined over the four vertices. How can I get a smooth variation of the color of the faces based on the value of the scalar field at the vertices?

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

# Create figure and axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# Create coordinates of the vertices
vertices = [np.array([[.25, 0., 0.], [.75, 0., 0.], [.75, .3, .5], [.25, .3, .5]]),
            np.array([[.25, .3, .5], [.75, .3, .5], [.75, .6, .5], [.25, .6, .5]]),
            np.array([[.25, .6, .5], [.75, .6, .5], [.75, .9, 1.], [.25, .9, 1.]])]
# Create random scalar field over the vertices
scalar = np.random.rand(3, 4)
# Modify scalar field such that values are consistent over coincident vertices
scalar[1, 0:2] = scalar[0, 2:]
scalar[2, 0:2] = scalar[1, 2:]
# Average scalar field over each face
averaged_scalar = np.mean(scalar, axis=1)
# Create 3d polygons
pc = Poly3DCollection(vertices, linewidths=.1)
# Create normalized colormap
m = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=mpl.cm.jet)
m.set_array(scalar)
m.set_clim(vmin=np.amin(averaged_scalar), vmax=np.amax(averaged_scalar))
rgba_array = m.to_rgba(averaged_scalar)
pc.set_facecolor([(i[0], i[1], i[2]) for i in rgba_array])
# Set color of the edges
pc.set_edgecolor('k')
# Add polygons to plot
ax.add_collection3d(pc)
# Show plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You could upsample your vertices and interpolate your scalar field at the new positions, then proceed as before.

Comment: Thanks Paul, it's a possible solution but a bit unpractical in my opinion.

Comment: Agree.  It seems a pity that all 3d render libraries support "vertex shading" but mplot does not.